# For what cardinals does exponentiation by a smaller cardinal is idempotent.

Tags: set-theory, exponentiation, cardinals, infinity

It is true that $\mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0}$ but $\mathfrak{c} < \mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c}$.

1. Is it true that $\mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{c}^{X}$ for all $X < \mathfrak{c}$?

The answer is obviously trivial if we admit the CH. In fact, if the GCH holds we get:

$\aleph_n = \aleph_n^{X}$ for all $X < \aleph_n$ and $n$ a

However, even with the GCH, the property does not hold in general, since $\aleph_{\omega} < \aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_0}$ (by [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory))). So,

2. For what cardinals $A$ does it hold that $A = A^B$ for all $A > B$?
3. Is there a relation $\mathcal{R}$ such that $A = A^B$ for all $\mathcal{R} A B$?

Comment: 1. is independent of the axioms of set theory.

Comment: For 2., any such cardinal $A$ is *regular*, but it is independent of the axioms of set theory whether this holds for any $A>\aleph_0$.

Comment: Are those statements true with CH or GCH, or also independent ?

Comment: CH solves 1 (positively), as you yourself pointed out. GCH gives 2. for all regular cardinals.

Comment: Let $A\mathcal R B$ iff $B=1.$ :-)

Comment: Elaborating on Andres' initial comment: it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\mathfrak{c}=\aleph_{\omega_1}$, in which case we have $\omega_1<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ but $(\aleph_{\omega_1})^{\omega_1}>\aleph_{\omega_1}$ (the latter inequality by Konig).